# meteor collection fs forbid upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, collectionfs

i want to forbid the upload / storage of files under special circumstances.

I tried in the collectionfs before hook:

```
Attachments.files.before.insert((userId, doc) => {
  if(!Meteor.isServer){
    if (!isUploadAllowed()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('Upload not allowed');
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Or can someone help me?

(An ugly solution would be to remove the uploaded document in the after.insert hook, i hope there is a better way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the deny for this collection for all client operations to false:

```
const Attachments.files = new Mongo.Collection('fs.files')
Attachments.files.deny({
  insert () { return true },
  update () { return true },
  remove () { return true }
})
```

This defaults to deny any client operation to sync with the server.

Comment: Yeah sure, with this i could completely disable uploads. But i need to change it dynamically, that was why i adapted into the before.insert hook. Or can your suggestion be executed during runtime?

Comment: Do you use a package like `ostrio:files` or do you realize the upload manually? If you want to prevent upload during runtime you should use roles like via `alanning:roles` package and show/hide uploads based on roles. In any way if you have certain permission levels for uploads you will have to check them again on the server, because client side checks can always be circumvented.

Comment: i have these packages included `cfs:base-package@0.0.30
cfs:gridfs@0.0.33
cfs:storage-adapter@0.2.1` but no `ostrio:files` nor `alanning:roles`

Comment: `or do you realize the upload manually?`what do you mean? Upload is done on client side, by drag and drop for instance.

Comment: Does the package "automagically" do the upload, do you upload by doing a client-side insert and let the Collection sync or do you call a Meteor method that sends the file via ddp to the server and then insert the files into gridFs?

Comment: We have an event on client where a file can be attached, this will trigger an insert in the attachments collection, which is: `new FS.Collection('attachments', { new FS.Store.GridFS('attachments'),
  ],...`

Comment: I had a thinking error, after thinking this throug, i guess / hope i can use what your first answer was.